# What is the word that best describes this?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word to describe a person who:

- Labels or has labelled another person with a specific negative label.

&

- Uses this label a lot when referring to that person.

Example sentence:

> "*Why do you keep calling him that? Stop being a* **[insert_word]**"

---

> "*Don't be too much of a* **[insert_word]**"

Comment: <Insert insult here>

Comment: I don't think there is word identifying this behavior in a single word. It has to capture the creation of a derogatory epithet, the repetitive usage and possibly the intent for the whole thing. I guess it's mostly just one feature of an overall repelling person for which no one really bothered to find a word. The plane of reason has long been outstripped, why try to address that singular trait.

Comment: The action of repeatedly using a negative epithet could be described as stigmatizing, defamatory, disparaging, etc.

Comment: The adjective "judgemental" may be of use. Usage is "Don't be so judgemental". This is slightly more generic than you seem to want though; it has nothing to do with "labels" specifically.

Comment: Okay, but It is certainly appropos nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***name-caller***

dictionary.com:

> **[name-caller](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/name-caller)**
>   *noun*
>
> **1.** a person who constantly resorts to name-calling.
>
> **[name-calling](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/name-calling)**
>   *noun*
>
> **1.** the use of abusive names to belittle or humiliate another person in a political campaign, an argument, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> "Why do you keep calling him that? Stop being a [insert_word]"

*labeller*

*bigot*

*racist* (if appropriate)

*ablist*

Or you could rewrite your sentence, for example,

> Stop thinking in terms of stereotypes.
>
> Try to see the person, not just the label.

Comment: I am not sure rewriting example sentences is a helpful approach to _single word requests._ After all the question is to find that word - or realizing that there is no such thing.

Comment: "Labeller" is pretty unusual - "Stop labeling people" would be a more familiar form, so it may not fit as a single word here. "Ablist" also has a specific meaning that may not be applicable.

Comment: @Backgammon - Oh. What is the specific meaning of *ablist* you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

***mudslinger*** (occasionally hyphenated as ***mud-slinger***):

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mudslinger):
>
>   one that makes malicious attacks
>     especially against a political opponent

You can also use ***broken record*** (Br.E.: ***stuck record***) as a
(somewhat archaic?) idiom for somebody who says the same thing(s) repeatedly,
but is not specific to the use of pejorative labels.

> [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/broken_record):
>
>   Used, especially in similes,
>     to refer to a person’s constant and annoying repetition
>     of a particular statement or opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A not-so-common word: **pigeonholer**

Reference: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pigeonholer)

> someone who likes to pigeonhole people or things

Google Ngram indicates it is [rarely used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pigeonholer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpigeonholer%3B%2Cc0), so it is really up to how desperate you are.